# How to randomize Panels in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple quiz game. I have four panels (questions), and I want to randomize these panels. More importantly, I want only one panel to be activated, and once a panel is generated it can not be generated again.

Note each panel is a question and contains an question image and three buttons (answers).

So I have four panels `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`.

I know the code is vague, but I am new at this and I really want to know.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject StartScreen;
public GameObject QuestionScreen;
public GameObject ResultsScreen;
public GameObject[] questions;
public static int CurrentQuestionIndex;

private void ShowstartScreen(){
    StartScreen.SetActive (true);
    QuestionScreen.SetActive (false);
    ResultsScreen.SetActive (false);    
}
private void ShowQuestionScreen(){
    StartScreen.SetActive (false);
    QuestionScreen.SetActive (true);
    ResultsScreen.SetActive (false);    
}public void StartButtonHandler(){
    ShowQuestionScreen ();
}
public void RandomizeQuestion (){
}
public void DisplayQuestion(){
}
void Start (){

    ShowstartScreen ();
}
```

In the functions `randomizeQuestions` and `displayquestion` what will I need?

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the questions (and answers) from the UI that displays them.
Have a seperate Question class and collection of all questions.

Here's a simple example

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Question {

    public string question;
    public string[] answer;
    public int correctAnswer;

    public Question(string question, string[] answer, int correctAnswer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }
}

//this could also be part of your monobehaviour, i just like things seperate
public class QuestionCollection {
    List<Question> questions;

    public QuestionCollection() {
        questions = new List<Question>();
    }

    public void AddQuestion(string question, string[] answers, int     correctAnswer) {
        questions.Add(new Question(question, answers, correctAnswer));
    }

    //here's where you get your random question
    public Question GetRandomQuestion() {
        //if theres any questions
        if(questions.Count > 0) {
            //we get a random index
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, questions.Count);
            //temporarily store the corresponding question
            Question q = questions[randomIndex];
            //remove it from the collection so it doesnt come up twice
            questions.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
            //and return it to the caller
            return q;
        }
       //there was no questions (either none has been added or were done) so we return null
       return null;
   }
}
```

You only need to find a way to fill the collection (the AddQuestion(...) method), either look into how to read from a text/xml/json/... file or you look into editor scripting and derive the classes from scriptable object instead.

Ofc for testing purpose you can fill it by hand. To fit all that in the above snippet you would do the following.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject StartScreen;
public GameObject QuestionScreen;
public GameObject ResultsScreen;

//those two are not needed anymore
//public GameObject[] questions;
//public static int CurrentQuestionIndex;

//a reference to the collection containing all the questions
QuestionCollection questions;
//the current question, or null if everything has been asked
Question currentQuestion;

private void ShowstartScreen(){
    StartScreen.SetActive (true);
    QuestionScreen.SetActive (false);
    ResultsScreen.SetActive (false);    
}
private void ShowQuestionScreen(){
    StartScreen.SetActive (false);
    QuestionScreen.SetActive (true);
    ResultsScreen.SetActive (false);    
}
public void StartButtonHandler(){
    ShowQuestionScreen ();
}
private void RandomizeQuestion (){
    //get a new random question
    currentQuestion = questions.GetRandomQuestion();
}
public void DisplayQuestion(){
    RandomizeQuestion();
    if(currentQuestion != null) {
         //fill out your Panels with currentQuestion.question, currentQuestion.answer[#]
    }
    else {
         //there is no question left to be asked.
    }

}
void Start (){

    //create the collection
    questions = new QuestionCollection();
    //fill the collection using this scheme
    questions.AddQuestion("Was the question answered?", new string[] { "Yes", "No" }, 0);

    ShowstartScreen ();
}
```

I hope theres no typos, this was written here, not in an IDE, so better doublecheck :D